# unable to obtain SVG rect computed style

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Really stucked here,

i had created a rectangular bar base on a % as the width. If i debug it, i do see the width in pixels in the computed menu. I had tried looking for a solution online but there arent any.

This is the SVG rect i had created, its part of a bar chart.

```
<rect style="fill: white;" id="g2005" x="39px" y="240px" width="44.95%" height="15px" onmouseover="graphMouseIn(id)" onmouseout="graphMouseOut(id)"></rect>
```

The following code where i put XXXXX is the place i want the magic to insert the computed width in pixel.

```
<animate attributeName="width" from="0" to="XXXXX" dur="0.10s" fill="freeze"></animate>
```

[image: The width in pixel that i want to grab.]

I had tried to do a couple of things to obtain it but it goes either undefined or null.

The following code gave me NULL

```
<animate attributeName="width" from="0" to=' + ($('#g' + sightingYear).width()) + ' dur="0.10s" fill="freeze" />
```

The following code gave me UNDEFINED

```
<animate attributeName="width" from="0" to=' + (('#g' + sightingYear).width) + ' dur="0.10s" fill="freeze" />
```

I had also tried using Window.getComputedStyle(), .InnerWidth, all did not work. Please help me, i appreciate your help!! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you can't call `getComputedStyle` on SVGElements (which jQuery `.width()`does call),  you need `el.getBoundincClientRect().width`

Comment: @Kaiido `el.getBoundincClientRect().width` will provide width in `px`.

Comment: @ozil, if I get the question correctly, that's what OP does want.

Comment: im sorry guys, im not a web designer guy, but what is e1? 
can i use it like (#g2005).getBoundincClientRect().width so as it points directly to the bar i wish to get the width?

Comment: `el` is your element, if you're using jQuery, it's `$(selector)[0]`. And sorry I made a typo, it's `getBoundingClientRect()`, not boundin**c**ClientRect...

Comment: @Kaiido Type Error: index.getBoundingClientRect() is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to work out the width in pixels?  Do you realise you can just use percentage values?

```
<animate attributeName="width" from="0%" to="44.95%"...
```

**Demo**

```html
<svg width="500" viewBox="0 0 500 15">
  <rect width="44.95%" height="15px">
    <animate attributeName="width" from="0%" to="44.95%" dur="3.10s" fill="freeze"></animate>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked alright, i figured that i had this animate element outside the rect element.

Comment: `<animate>` doesn't need to be inside the `<rect>` as I have done in my example.  It can be outside if you wish.